# How to call RBG parameters from object in Java

Tags: java, colors

I'm in the process of writing an accessor for an object from the Color class. I'd like to return the sum of the red, green, and blue values associated with the object. Is there a way for me to call the parameters of the object I created?

this is what i've tried so far to no avail....

```
//  Sample  //



int red = 200;
int green = 51;
int blue = 76;

Color c = new Color(red, green, blue);
System.out.println(c.red);
System.out.println(c.green);
System.out.println(c.blue);

// The above gives a compile error //
```

Comment: Please show `Color` source

Comment: Is this Color c = new Color(red, green, blue) or this
System.out.println(c.red); causing problem ?

Comment: Note that `c.red` does **not** point to the internal red-value of your color object. It rather points to the constant `Color` object that represents a full red color *(255, 0, 0)*. That variable is **static** and thus it should be referenced by `Color.red` instead of `c.red` because it is not a member of your `c` object but of the class `Color`. If you want to access the red-property of your `c` object then you should use `c.getRed()`. Just as a note, `Color` also defines other constants for all kind of colors, like `Color.BLACK` or `Color.LIGHTBLUE` for example.

Comment: For future questions, please always also include the exact error message. It contains information which part of you code actually throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to find this information is usually within the Java documentation - for the Color class you can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

To answer your question, if you have a Color object you should be able to call c.getBlue(), c.getRed(), and c.getGreen() and they should be returned as ints.

Comment: can i get the values without creating new accessors?

Comment: What do you mean? If you are using the Java Color class, the accessors are part of the class, you just need to have a Color object.

Comment: You do not need to create such methods by yourself, if that is the question. This *getter-methods* are part of the `Color` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue().

```
import java.awt.*;

public class colors123 {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int red = 200;
    int green = 51;
    int blue = 76;

    Color c = new Color(red, green, blue);
    System.out.println(c.getRed());
    System.out.println(c.getGreen());
    System.out.println(c.getBlue());
    System.out.println(c.getRed()+c.getGreen()+c.getBlue());

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without new accessors for each color?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Whats the problem with the above code? The `Color` class does not offer a direct access to its internals, they are marked as **package visible**. Therefore they offer this **getter** methods. Note that the `Color` object does not even memorize the colors as you think. It stores them efficiently inside one `int` using byte manipulation as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/xKjN2rc.jpg. You can take a look at the whole source code by yourself, for example here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java